# Custom Column layout Python API

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, tornado

I am working on a small project as a backend developer. Front team working on UI page which has columns such as Name, Price, Discount, etc. 
Now a client(user) have the privilege that he can select any column which he wants to see only & save in its personnel layout. for eg.
   Layout1: Name, Price
   Layout2 : Name, Discount
   Layout3(user saved this as default for him): Name, Price, Discount

Below is the table which I have created using SQLAlchemy.

```
db_string = "postgres://user@10.**.**.***:####demo_db"
Base = declarative_base()
db = create_engine(db_string)   #Connecting postgre with SQL Alchemy

class Layout(Base):
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "col"} 
    __tablename__ = "layout" 
    name = Column(String(1000), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key = True)
    layoutdata = Column(String(10000), nullable=False)
    userid = Column(String(1000), nullable=False)
    isdefaultlayout = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
```

layoutdata is in JSON format which contains keys as columns for layout having user-specific data.

How can I proceed? I don't know where to start and where to end. Any suggestions, help means a lot

Comment: API should not be responsible for UI specific logic. API's job is to send out data requested by fronted. Your frontend should make a request to the API to receive the `layoutdata`, and then make another request to API to get the required columns. It's not API's job to send out data required by UI. It's the other way round: UI requests the data from API that it needs.

Comment: @xyres If UI asks for user-specific layoutdata and required columns, how would I send to UI?

Comment: Make HTTP request like `/api/data/?fields=name,price,data` and then in the backend iterate over the field names and use `getattr(ClassName, 'price')` to get the values from db.